# Where is the documentation for the ACL module/api?

Tags: users

Has anyone successfully created a client module that controls node access via the ACL module? I installed this module and created my own UIs to populate the three tables: acl, acl_node and acl_user. I started to create nodes, which populated acl_node with appropriate values, but nothing else seemed to happen. No new realm in the node-access table, nothing. Have I missed a step? I can't find any documentation on this module/api. Thanks.

The notes in the nodes_access_example module (part of the examples project) encourage you to 'read up' on the ACL module. I can't find anything to read though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you take a look at the [ACL project page](https://drupal.org/project/acl), you'll see that the following four client modules exist:

- [Content Access](http://drupal.org/project/content_access)
- [Flexi Access](https://drupal.org/project/flexiaccess)
- [Forum Access](http://drupal.org/project/forum_access)
- [Image Gallery Access](http://drupal.org/project/image_gallery_access)

You'll find plenty of examples on how to use the API in the source code of those.

The documentation for ACL are the comments embedded inside `acl.module`.  They are quite helpful when you try to create a client module.

P.S.: I am the maintainer of Flexi Access.  I can verify that ACL works as advertised.

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful. I didn't think about looking in another module that successfully uses this api. In the end I built my own thing with hook_node_grants and hook_node_access_records - perhaps a better way to go for a node-access table first-timer - but I may come back to this api in the future and have another go.